# Looking for an Item in a UL

Tags: jquery

My Unordered List tree structure is as follows:

```
<ul id="Budor">
    <li class="L-1">First
        <span class='jor'>+</span>
        <ul>
           <li class="L-2">First Child
               <span class='jor'>+</span>
              <ul>
                  <li>Tropical Thunder</li>
                  <li>Magnolia</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

I am typing some text in the text box and searching for an item in this list. Here's my demo http://jsfiddle.net/yunabna5/

I am facing three main issues:

1. On every character typed, the list closes and opens.
2. The list item as well as the parents also get highlighted. I want that only the list items with the search term should get highlighted.
3. Once the list is being searched, I cannot expand the other lists

How do I fix my code? Suggestions?

Comment: this might explain why the parent is being highlighted...  `console.log($('.L-2:first').text())`. It also contains the text of it's descendents.

Comment: and how do I fix it?

Comment: will have more control by using jQuery `filter()`. Then check if element has sub UL, also can convert case within filter also if you don't want current case sensitive search

Comment: filter()? Can you show a working demo?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txt').keyup(function () {
if(this.value == ""){
    bud.find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    bud.find("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    return;
}

if(bud.find('.highlight').length == 0){
    bud.find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
}

bud.find("li ul")
   .find('ul')
   .find('li:contains(' + this.value + ')')
   .addClass("highlight");

 bud.find('li.highlight')
    .stop(true)
    .parentsUntil(bud)
    .slideDown(500);
```

});

I think that this solve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/yunabna5/10/ if not tell me why.

Comment: Yes it resolves the parent highlighting issue but the search does not work as expected. Try searching 'tecss' and you will see that Dorothy gets highlighted which is wrong.

Comment: Try create a function with indexOf http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp or '===' http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp to check if the ul/li have the string that the user is typing.

The actually code match Dorothy because this have 't' that is inside the 'Tecss'.